# terms in topology and real analysis are the same or different?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I started to study topology recently, and encountered the concept of "interior", "exterior", "closure" and so on in topological concept.

At the first glance, the definitions of each term seemed different from real analysis, but when I looked at an example (geometry example in a plane), they seemed the same from real analysis.

I just wonder if the terms are the same in both real analysis and topology, or can be different.

If it can be different, can you please give me a simple example.

Thanks,

Comment: May you include the definitions that you mentioned?

Comment: Real analysis frequently approaches things from the point of view of sequences or specializes to metric spaces, rather than from the point of view of open sets. But generally, the objects can be shown to be equivalent.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Interior point in topology is defined:
Let (X,$\tau$) be a topological space and let $A \subset X$. The interior of $A$ is the set INT$(A) = U_{i\in \mathcarl{I}}\{u_i | u_i \subset A \; \text{and} \; u_i \in \tau \}$. while in real analysis:

point $x\in A$ is an interior point if there exists an open ball around $x\; \forall r>0$, $B_r(x)\in A$.

Comment: @user1292919 Mostly the terminology is universal.  Certainly interior, exterior, closure are the same *concepts* everywhere.  Though since they all have several equivalent definitions each author will choose to start with one and make the equivalence with the others results.  But there are some terms that vary.  Like some authors say "boundary" while others say "frontier".  Each treatment should be clear about their definitions up front.